# Accessing elements of a sharedctypes Array

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, ctypes

I am trying to **save memory by sharing memory** between processes using the sharedctypes part of the multiprocessing module.

The example given in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) requires the values of the c array to be recovered, in the example they where put in a list, before being used:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value, Array
from ctypes import Structure, c_double

class Point(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_double), ('y', c_double)]

def modify(n, x, s, A):
    n.value **= 2
    x.value **= 2
    s.value = s.value.upper()
    for a in A:
        a.x **= 2
        a.y **= 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    n = Value('i', 7)
    x = Value(c_double, 1.0/3.0, lock=False)
    s = Array('c', b'hello world', lock=lock)
    A = Array(Point, [(1.875,-6.25), (-5.75,2.0), (2.375,9.5)], lock=lock)

    p = Process(target=modify, args=(n, x, s, A))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(n.value)
    print(x.value)
    print(s.value)
    print([(a.x, a.y) for a in A])             <---- THIS LINE
```

Surely this **negates** the **memory saved** by sharing between processes because the shared **information** is **copied** exactly as if each process had loaded the information individually. Please correct me if I am miss understanding the way this is working (*which I probably am*).

My **Question**: Can the **information** in the sharedctypes array `A` be **accessed directly**?

I had imagined something like this:

```
print(A[:])                    <-- prints all values from A
```

instead of:

```
print([a for a in A])          <-- creates a new list of values in A, then prints
```

Comment: Note: `A[:]` also creates a new list.

Comment: @ikkuk surely A[:] recalls the values directly from A? no need for a completely new list?

Comment: [Documentation on lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) says slicing with `[:]` creates a new list. Testing with `Array` seems to give the same results for me.

Comment: fair enough, it was not really the point of my question, but I apologies if I was unclear. `A[:]` was meant to indicate getting the values directly from memory not creating a list and therefore taking up even more memory